# $wpdb->insert splits my date after I formatted

Tags: jquery, mysql, wordpress, insert

Here is the script that you would think would work out of the box.

```
function ajax_away_dates() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
  $bookonline = $wpdb->prefix . "book_online";
  $dateedit = $_POST['data'];
  $date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dateedit));
  $wpdb->insert(
    $bookonline,
    array(
        'allday' => 1,
        'appiontmentdate' => $date
    ),
    array(
        '%s',
        '%d'
    )
);

//  $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $bookonline ('allDay','appiontmentdate') SET ('1','$dateedit')");
print $wpdb->last_query;
  return $wpdb->print_error();  /*$whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever;
  */
    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

I also tried

```
$date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dateedit));
  $query = array(
        'allDay' => 1,
        'appiontmentdate' => $date
    );
  $wpdb->insert(
    $bookonline,
    $query);
```

and the jQuery

```
function senttocalserver(d){
      jQuery.post(
      ajaxurl,
      {
          'action': 'calendaradd',
          'data':   d
      },
      function(response){
          alert('The server responded: ' + response);
      }
      );
    }
```

URL encodes like

```
action=calendaradd&data=2015-12-7
```

But what happens is it stops after 2015 see below

```
The server responded: INSERT INTO `zo_book_online` (`allday`, `appiontmentdate`) VALUES ('1', 2015)0
```

Comment: what you are getting  here ` $date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dateedit));`, have you tried `var_dump()` if you are getting it correct.check date format of `current_time( 'mysql' )` and change the format to `current_time( 'mysql' )` if possible and try .

Answer (score 0):

```
 $wpdb->insert(
    $bookonline,
    array(
        'allday' => 1,
        'appiontmentdate' => $date
    ),
    array(
        '%s',
        '%d'
    )
);
```

here  '`%d`' represents you are inserting integer , `remove array( '%s', '%d' )` that are optional part and that should work .

That will be

```
$wpdb->insert(
        $bookonline,
        array(
            'allday' => 1,
            'appiontmentdate' => $date
        )
    );
```

Comment: even tried this $date=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dateedit));
  $query = array(
  'allDay' => 1,
  'appiontmentdate' => $date
 );
  $wpdb->insert(
 $bookonline,
 $query);

Comment: @RussellHarrower  this should work, no idea why not working.I will try to figure out and let you know.